# how I can control POST request in htaccess with php regular expression?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, post

How can I control POST request in htaccess with php regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Use `REQUEST_METHOD` to match only `POST` requests.

This will send all POST requests to `handler.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /handler.php?_path=$1
```

Comment: with php regular expression?

Comment: Yep, both PHP and `mod_rewrite` use PCRE.

Comment: I added an example `RewriteRule`.

Comment: is your example special for POST only?